# variadic template function (to delete number of dynamically allocated variables)

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

I don't get exactly if I am doing the right thing

```
template<typename ...AllVArgs>
auto dealloc_all(AllVArgs &..._AllVArgs) -> void {
 (((std::cout << "\nin dealloc_all function " << &_AllVArgs), ...) << " ");

 ((delete _AllVArgs), ...);
 ((_AllVArgs), ...) = nullptr;
}
```

I allocated 2 struct and try to free them by using the variadic template function

```
struct a {
 int x;
}
```

```
a *v1 = new a();
a *v2 = new a();

std::cout << "\nin a function " << &v1<< " " << &v2;
//address output = 0x1dce9ff588 0x1dce9ff580

dealloc_all(v1, v2);
```

I just wanted to know if I successfully free the allocated memory. btw these are the output it gives me, and I think there's no problem with it?

```
in a function 0xa4b89ff5c8 0xa4b89ff5c0
in dealloc_all function 0xa4b89ff5c8   
in dealloc_all function 0xa4b89ff5c0
```

Comment: You could pass this through valgrind and check if there are any leaks. The code seems fine though, do you have some reason to think it might not be correct?

Comment: Identifiers starting with underscore followed by upper-case letter are reserved in all contexts. You may not declare them.

Comment: Avoid owning bare pointers.

Comment: pretty sure `((_AllVArgs), ...) = nullptr` should be `((_AllVArgs = nullptr), ...)`.  The first is only going to assign `nullptr` to the last parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just wanted to know if I successfully free the allocated memory.

Yes: with

```
((delete _AllVArgs), ...);
```

you correctly free all the allocated memory

> I don't get exactly if I am doing the right thing

Not completely: with

```
((_AllVArgs), ...) = nullptr;
```

you set to null pointer **only** the last argument of your function. If you want to set to null pointer **all** arguments, you have to rewrite your folding as follows

```
((_AllVArgs = nullptr), ...);
```

To verify what I say, I've rewritten your code as follows

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct a
{ ~a() { std::cout << "deleting a" << std::endl; } };

template <typename ... Args>
auto dealloc_all (Args & ... as)
{
  std::cout << "before delete" << std::endl;

  ((delete as), ...);

  std::cout << "after delete" << std::endl;

  ((as), ...) = nullptr;
}


int main()
{
  a *v1 = new a();
  a *v2 = new a();

  std::cout << "\nbefore function " << v1<< " " << v2 << std::endl;

  dealloc_all(v1, v2);

  std::cout << "\nafter function " << v1<< " " << v2 << std::endl;
}
```

so you can see that "deleting a" is written two times between "before delete" and "after delete"; so the destructor (called when you delete an allocated object) is called for every `as...` object.

But you can also see something as

```
 after function 0x55b20b759eb0 0
```

printing the values of `v1` and `v2` (observe: I print the values of the pointers, not the addresses); if you want

```
 after function 0 0
```

you have to change

```
 ((as), ...) = nullptr;
```

to

```
 ((as = nullptr), ...);
```